# React map inside a map, multi array in an object

Tags: reactjs, object, map-function

I have a map function inside a map function in react for this object

```
let timelineElements=[{
    id: 2,
    title: "Backend Developer",
    location: "Skystead, Craonia",
    description: [
      "Recommend changes for reporting to enhance the overall monitoring of system, vulnerabilities and practices",

      "Built data pipeline that allowed automated and efficient way of reporting using Powershell scripting, Excel , SQL and Power BI that",
    ],
    buttonText: "View Backend Projects",
    date: "June 2013 - August 2016",
    icon: "work",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Quality Assurance Engineer",
    location: "South Warren, Geshington",

    description: [
      "Recommend changes for reporting to enhance the overall monitoring of system, vulnerabilities and practices",

      "Built data pipeline that allowed automated and efficient way of reporting using Powershell scripting, Excel , SQL and Power BI that",
    ],
    date: "September 2011 - June 2013",
    icon: "work",
  }]
```

and I already have this set up

```
 {timelineElements.map((element) => {
     return (
    <p key={element.key}>
    {element.title}
    </p>
    {element.description && element.description.map((desc) => {return (<p key={desc}>{desc}</p>);
})}

)}
```

I added the ** ** in the description item so that you could see where I am trying to access the data.
but in the application there is no ** ** in the description.

I think that the logic holds and that it should work but when I run this
I get this error
[image: error]

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: Error is saying that you've *some* `element.description` that isn't an array or isn't an object with a `map` function property to invoke. You're mapping also doesn't appear to be valid JSX, is this a complete example? There seems to be something missing? Is anything updating the `timelineElements` value?

Comment: this is not the full code but rather the logic of how it is being implemented. I had to shorten it because my code is about 100 lines and I didn't want you to read all that code. There is nothing updating the timelineElements value.
Hope that answered your question

Comment: Are you fetching the timelineElements from a API call ?

Comment: Ok, seems we need a bit more context. From what you've shared there isn't anything that could throw the error, so I'm assuming there's more to the story in the code you omitted. It doesn't need to be your *entire* code (100 lines isn't a lot, BTW), but we should see where `timelineElements` is declared, all logic that updates it (for any reason), all the way to where you are trying to render it. Somewhere along the line it appears `description` becomes *not* an array or mappable object.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not sure whether the description will always be `[]` that sometimes you might get `null` as well . Then you can use `optional chaining`

```
{element?.description && element.description.map((desc) => {return (<p key={desc}>{desc}</p>);
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.map` can handle empty arrays without issue, provided what you are trying to map is *actually* an array. You would only need to check the length if you wanted to conditionally render some other UI if there was nothing to map.

Comment: yeah but the error says `.map` is not a function . But what you said is correct my first answer is not needed . But the optional chaining part might help .

Comment: The Optional Chaining really only helps if the object you are referencing into is possibly null or undefined, it can still fail with the OP's error if it ***is*** defined but not an array or object with `map` property to call as a function, i.e. like if `description` is a string, or number, etc.

Comment: yeah got it, thats why i have mentioned if it is null in the answer . But i doubt this might be because of the way he is setting the initial state .

Answer (score 1):

```
{(element?.description || []).map((desc) => {return (<p key={desc}>{desc}</p>);
```